# Push Sharp ios notification getting error with distribution certificate "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException"

Tags: c#, ios, .net, asp.net-mvc, apple-push-notifications

I am working on apple push notification using Push Sharp. It's working good on my local machine with development and distribution certificates. I did receive push notification when i tried locally. But, When I moved the code to my production server (GODaddy server), I am receiving an error

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException).

PushBroker _pushBroker = new PushBroker();
                var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificates/App_AdHoc.p12"));
                _pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCert, "pamten")); //Extension method
                _pushBroker.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                        .ForDeviceToken("Device Token")
                        .WithAlert("Message")
                        .WithBadge(0)
                        .WithSound("default")
                        );
```

Below is the error i am getting in GoDaddy server.

```
ExceptionType": "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException",
5   "StackTrace": " at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)\r\n at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)\r\n at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)\r\n at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)\r\n at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)\r\n at PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushChannelSettings..ctor(Boolean production, Byte[] certificateData, String certificateFilePwd, Boolean disableCertificateCheck)\r\n at InStorePal.Controllers.InStorePalController.GetItemsList(GetItems obj)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
6   }
```

I have tried lot of ways like **access permissions for the folders in GODaddy server, created distributed certificates** so many times.

Please help me. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue in GoDaddy Server. Try Azure or Amazon server once.
It worked for me in Azure.

Its a strange issue and strange solution. But it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult ios()
    {
        var certi = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificatesgit.p12");
        var appleCert = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificatesgit.p12"));

        ApnsConfiguration apnsConfig = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Production, appleCert, "password");

        string message = string.Empty;
        var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(apnsConfig);

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
        {
            aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
            {
                if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                {
                    var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;
                    var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                    var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;
                    var inner = notificationException.InnerException;
                    message = "IOS Push Notifications: Apple Notification Failed: ID=" + apnsNotification.Identifier + ", Code=" + statusCode + ", Inner Exception" + inner;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "IOS Push Notifications: Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : " + ex.InnerException;
                }
                return true;
            });
        };

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
        {
            message = "IOS Push Notifications: Apple Notification Sent!";
        };

        apnsBroker.Start();
        try
        {
            string deviceToken = "4e16e1439d7f1a342ed5a8c92bf029503107c7a2bc3b92b794b22665affcf99c";

            apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
            {
                DeviceToken = deviceToken,
                Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":7}}")
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        apnsBroker.Stop();

        return View(message);
    }
```